# Linear Regression with Sparse Matrices

Tags: r

I'm writing code for a predictive model where there is a constraint on file size. Therefore, I'm using a sparse matrix as my predictor. There are various kinds of sparse matrices (dgCMatrix, dgTMatrix, csr, etc.) but the most efficient of them in terms of memory size is the csr matrix. The problem I'm having is in choosing which package to perform Ridge (or lightgbm) regression on a csr matrix with.

So far, I've found:
glmnet does not predict with csr matrices.
lightgbm does not predict with csr matrices.
even the neuralnet doesnt predict with csr matrices in my experience.

Does anyone know of a regression package in R that allows csr matrices as inputs? I know python does this easily, but I'm not knowledgable enough to get there.

Comment: The biglm package can perform regression on models that are too large to fit into memory.

Comment: If you could please provide some code, including a data generating process which roughly mirrors your data, that would be greaaat. Include the packages you are already using. Thaaanks!